# filter data by Date range Javascript-jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, date

I have data from API where date format is yyyy-mm-dd.
I have added a bootstrap date range picker plugin whose date format is dd/mm/yyyy.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function (){
            $('#from').datepicker({
                format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
            });
            $('#to').datepicker({
                format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
            });
        });
```

I want to show data by filtering date range. help me.

```
 function show_date(){
    if ($("#from").val().length == 0 || $("#to").val().length == 0) {
         alert('All fields are required');
     } else {
         alert($("#from").val() + ' to ' + $("#to").val());
     }
}
```

Comment: Then why don't you specify target format while initializing datepicker.
``$('#from').datepicker({
                format: "YYYY-MM-DD"
            });``

Comment: Wheres that data coming from?

Comment: i have tried "YYYY-MM-DD" but the datepicker is not responding to it @abhijith

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
 });
```

- formats: dd, d, mm, m, yyyy, yy
- separators: -, /, .

[Source](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/). I have extracted it from here. You can get full year with 'yy'.